# Разница между двоичным и байт кодом?

Tags: кодировка, компилятор

Парни я  честно  гуглил(правда с телефона) минут 40.
Двоичный код это (условный пример 0101110010)
Байт код (на примере JVM) компилятор берет код на java-> байт код->машинный код 
Вопрос  двоичный код и байт код это одно и тоже ????
Если нет...то подробней пожалуйста

Comment: Байт код -- это промежуточный код между двоичным (машинным) и, к примеру, кодом на java. Двоичный код -- это инструкции для конкретной ОС и архитектуры процессоров. Например, байт код у одной и той же программы будет одинаковый, но двоичный код получится разный для: windows и linux

Comment: Двоичный (шестнадцатеричный, восьмеричный) код - это текстовый вид (в виде набора символов) внутреннего представления данных. Байт-код - это набор инструкций для виртуальной машины (по сути, данные в виде набора байт). Байт-код может быть представлен в виде двоичного кода, но это не одно и то же.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Небольшая историческая справка.

В самых первых компьютерах (1940-е годы) команды и данные хранились раздельно. Данные располагались в памяти, а команды задавались перемычками на лицевой панели. Из-за этого некоторые команды нельзя было реализовать в принципе. Например, нельзя было передать управление на команду, адрес которой хранится в памяти. Сейчас с помощью таких *косвенных* вызовов работают *виртуальные методы* в Java/C++/C#.

Группа инженеров предложила несколько архитектурных принципов, которые помогли сделать компьютеры проще и в то же время мощнее. Один из них гласит, что и программы и данные хранятся в оперативной памяти. Поскольку компьютер не хранит ничего кроме чисел, процессор «видит» программу именно как массив чисел.

Сейчас эти принципы называются *архитектурой Фон Неймана* по имени американского математика, который был участником группы, разработавшей первые компьютеры. Большая историческая несправедливость состоит в том, что Фон Нейман не руководил этой группой, и, скорее всего, не придумал ни одного из предложенных принципов. Но в опубликованной статье его фамилия стояла первой, и именно поэтому принципы получили такое название.

Числа хранятся в двоичном виде (ещё один принцип архитектуры Фон Неймана). Минимальной единицей хранения является байт. Я читал, что существовали компьютеры с 7-битными и 9-битными словами, но никогда их не видел. Насколько я знаю, уже в конце 60-х годов победил 8-битный байт.

Вот пример машинного кода и его представления на языке Ассемблера. Я нашёл его в Google. Слева указан порядковый номер (адрес) первого байта команды. Во второй колонке мы видим байты команды, они записаны в восьмеричной системе счисления. В третьей колонке мнемоники Ассемблера, которые упрощают восприятие программы человеком. Некоторые команды занимают один байт, а некоторые два. В этом примере нет команд, которые занимают три, четыре и больше байт, но такие команды также встречаются.

```
004: 003 010       lbl adda    #8      immediate value decimal
006: 103 010           addb    #010    same thing in octal
010: 024 001           lda     b       memory reference
012: 235 220           stx     (ptr)   indirect reference
014: 306 204           ora     data,x  indexed
016: 337 220           lnega   (ptr),x indirect/indexed
020:               # jumps and calls
020: 344 004           jmp     lbl     unconditional jump
022: 043 030           jane    lbl2-2  jump if a not equal 0
024: 257 221           jxgt    (ptr+one) jump indirect if x gt
026: 364 041           call    sub     call to subroutine
030: 174 220           cbeq    (ptr)   call indirect if b eq 0
032:               # set and skips
032:                   lbl2
032: 122 204           set1    fox,2  set bit 2 of data to 1
034: 272 205           skp0    data+1,7  skip if bit 7 is 0
036:               # shifts and rotates
036: 001               shra    1+SHIFT   shift a right 4 plcs
037: 361               rolb    2       rotate b left 2 places
040: 000               hlt             halt
041: 000               sub db 0            return address
042: 200               nop             no op
043: 023 222           lda #0222
045: 123 144           ldb #100
047: 360               sys             system call (extension)
050: 023 222           sysp 0222,100   system call using parms
052: 123 144
054: 360
055: 354 041           jmp (sub)       return
```

Именно это и есть *двоичный код*, который «понимает» процессор.

Теперь о байт-коде. Основной проблемой двоичного кода является его специфичность. Два разных устройства, например, ноутбук и мобильный телефон, имеют разные процессоры и разные наборы команд.

Если мы захотим написать для них программу, нам придётся писать две программы. Традиционно проблема переносимости решается с помощью языков высокого уровня и компиляторов. Хороший компилятор — это сложная программа, которую долго разрабатывать и трудно поддерживать. Если наш компилятор имеет создавать код для пяти разных процессоров, в нём пять разных оптимизаторов и пять генераторов кода.

Проблему переносимости и сложности можно решить с помощью *промежуточной виртуальной машины*. Она должна иметь архитектуру низкого уровня, чтобы её можно было просто реализовать. С другой стороны, она должна включать в себя возможности современных процессоров, чтобы не проседать в производительности.

Виртуальный процессор работает также, как и реальный: он видит массив чисел, и воспринимает их как команды для выполнения. Байт-код внешне совершенно идентичен двоичному коду. Вот пример байт-кода виртуальной машины Java:

```
000: 03        iconst_0
001: 3b        istore_0
002: 84 00 01  iinc 0, 1
005: 1a        iload_0
006: 05        iconst_2
007: 68        imul
010: 3b        istore_0
011: a7 ff f9  goto -7
```

Единственная разница заключается в том, что двоичный код исполняет физический процессор, а байт-код — очень простая программа-интерпретатор. Впрочем, насколько я знаю, существуют физические процессоры, которые умеют выполнять байт-код Java-машины, так что разница между ними может быть и совсем условной.

Comment: А если учесть, что есть несколько линеек процессоров (включая последние процессоры от Intel), которые только притворяются x86-совмстимыми, а на самом деле внутри имеют другую архитектуру и микрокод интерпретатора машинных кодов x86, то разница размывается еще сильнее

Comment: Есть еще и QEMU, который (при отключенной аппаратной виртуализации) тоже является интерпретатором, байт-кодом для которого является бинарный код эмулируемой платформы.

Answer (score 5):

Двоичный/бинарный код - это код команд физического процессора. Он исполняется непосредственно.

Байт-код - это код команд некоторого программного виртуального исполнителя. В случае с Java - это JVM (Java Virtual Machine). Этот код интерпретируется JVM. Т.е. читается файл с байт-кодами, JVM берет очередной и выполняет соответствующую ему подпрограмму.

Существует еще техника JIT-компиляции, когда байт-код преобразуется непосредственно в команды процессора, и получившийся бинарный код уже исполняется физическим процессором.